# normal approximation of binomial distribution ("overbooking")

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, binomial-distribution

for the following example of an "Overbooking" I have to calculate the probability by using the Central Limit Theorem:

- An airline books 52 seats whilst there are only 50 seats available. A guest appears with a probability of 90%. What's the probablity that maximum 50 guests are coming?

I thought about normal approximation:

- $P(0 \leq S_n \leq 50) \approx \phi (\frac{50+0.5-µ}{\sigma}) - \phi (\frac{0-0.5-µ}{\sigma})$.
- $µ = np = 52\cdot 0.1 = 5.2$.
- $\sigma = \sqrt{npq} = \sqrt{4.68}$

Finally I get $0.99978$, whereas the probability by using binomial distribution gives me $0.9717$.

Have I done it correctly or are there some mistakes?

Comment: $np=52*0.9=52-5.2=46.8$

Comment: @callculus Alright, now I get a probability of 0.956397 - correct?

Comment: Yes. Your result is correct. It is $\Phi(1.7103)=0.95639$

Comment: It has been over two years. Would you consider deleting this question post? Back then you have already got your answer and moved on.

Comment: Hello? Are you there? Please post an answer and "accept" it yourself or delete the question, otherwise it's clogging up the system.